# How can I get a table of counts grouped by month on axis x and by hour on axis y in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

There is a log table with a lot of events, I would like to know what is statistical data, i.e. at what hour each month how many events happened.

```
Data sample:
 date_create         | event
---------------------+---------------------------
 2018-03-01 18:00:00 | Something happened
 2018-03-05 18:15:00 | Something else happened
 2018-03-06 19:00:00 | Something happened again
 2018-04-01 18:00:00 | and again
```

The result should look like this:

```
 hour | 03 | 04
------+----+----
 18   |  2 |  1
 19   |  1 |  0
```

I can make it with CTE, but then it is significant manual work each time. My guess would be that it can be made with funciton, but probably it is already there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation.  I'm thinking:

```
select extract(hour from date_create) as hh,
       sum(case when extract(month from date_create) = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as month_03,
       sum(case when extract(month from date_create) = 4 then 1 else 0 end) as month_04
from t
group by hh
order by hh;
```